# Webpack warning when upgrading Angular 6

Tags: angular

I upgraded Angular from version 6.0.0 to 6.1.3. After running `ng update @angular/core` I got the following warning:

```
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@6.0.8 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || 
~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
```

What is the meaning of `peer of typescript` ? According to `ng -version`, typescript is installed. What's the version `@ngtools/webpack`  is looking for?

ng -version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.4
Node: 8.9.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.4
@angular/cli                      6.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.7.4
@schematics/update                0.7.4
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: It says you have to install either of these typescript versions `typescript@~2.4.0 || 
~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0` to be compatible with the angular version that you have installed.. So you have to downgrade your typescript version.

Comment: But how would I know that downgrading typescript won't affect Angular?

Comment: You could look at the dependency on Typescript for your version of Angular. Just check the `package.json`

Comment: in `package.json` I see in `devDependencies` `"typescript": "~2.9.2"`, that seems to be the typescript version I have installed, not the Angular requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update the  "@angular-devkit/build-angular" to 0.7.4 to fix the above error.

Comment: it don't work for me. my environment is Wins10, Angular 7  
now the warning message become   
````@ngtools/webpack@6.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 || ~2.8.0 || ~2.9.0 but none is installed."````

Comment: Works great for Angular 6 upgrades on Win10!